# Error en instalacion de Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Alguien me podria ayudar para ver una solucion a la instalacion de angular 7 por favor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error simplemente dice que no tienes acceso al repositorio de npm... ¿Estás detrás de un proxy o un firewall?

Comment: Así como lo indica Pablo y la decripción del error, es un problema de red, además de que puede que tu conexión de red esté intermitente

Comment: El problema era la red intermitente, muchas gracias.